# Is it possible to programmatically get list of URLs from URL Tracker?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We are using `IContentFinder` implementation to route Umbraco pages to products in external database. Categories are managed in Umbraco. Turns out, if we rename category, the old CATEGORY page will automatically redirect to the new via (via the URL tracker), but if I open `old_category/productId` page, redirection does not happen. I need either to get access to all *old* URLs in order to find the relevant *new* URL - or check if `old_category` node redirects to the new URL.

How can I do that programmatically? I'm using Umbraco 7.11

I'm talking about this tab:
[image: Umbraco CMS]

Answer (score 1):

The URL Tracker stores its data in the `umbracoRedirectUrl` table, so you should be able to use this to get what you need.

There are also some DTO's for accessing the data you need in the source code. They might be left as internal, but you could duplicate them for your own use.